# Why does the OS need a page table if the MMU already has one?

Tags: operating-system, mmu

I'm confused about where the line between OS and MMU for virtual memory management is drawn.

If the MMU is responsible for translating virtual addresses to physical addresses and has an internal page table, why does the OS need to have a page table as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MMU needs to be told how the OS wants it to translate virtual addresses into physical addresses (and often, when not to translate at all - e.g. if the page at a virtual address needs to be fetched from disk, or if an access to a page should be treated as a programmer error - e.g. dereferencing a NULL pointer).

To do this, the OS provides page tables, and the MMU uses the page tables to translate virtual addresses into physical addresses for the OS.

Essentially, the OS and MMU share the page tables (and the MMU doesn't have its own).

Note that the MMU may cache translations (e.g. TLB entries) to improve performance, but a (limited size) cache isn't the same as the complete original table/s. There are also some (less common) architectures where the MMU only has a cache and doesn't use page tables at all (and when there's a "TLB miss" the CPU/MMU asks the OS to figure out what the translation should be), which is more flexible (the OS can use whatever it likes for page tables because it doesn't have to match what the MMU expects) but slower (higher TLB miss costs).

Comment: So the MMU is basically just to speed up the process of translating? And the OS already knows the mapping of each virtual to physical page?

Comment: Yes, MMU makes it fast enough to be practical (e.g. software can't translate "virtual address of instruction pointer" for every instruction); and OS knows what the OS wants (and knows when to change what it wants - e.g. when a process is started or stopped, or calls `mmap()` or `brk()`, or data is transferred to/from swap space, or data is transferred to/from memory mapped files, or...).

Comment: Does the MMUs you mentioned (that have more storage than just the cache) usually contain the complete page tables provided by the OS? What is that storage called?

Comment: I mentioned 2 alternatives - one where page tables are shared between OS and MMU (and MMU may also has cache); and one (less common) where MMU only has cache (and nothing else)